# Texto Encimado En Angular con Boostrap

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Hola chicos Tengo un problema al momento de que meto codigo todo el texto se encima estoy usando solo librerias de angular y de boostrap pero mieren lo que pasa no se por que esta pasando esto o si falta alguna libreria que agregar

```
    <div class="container-fluid p-t-15">
    <div class="main-card-title">
      <!-- <span class="title-text">Home Page</span>-->
    </div>
    <div class="main-card-content p-l-r-0 m-b-15">
      <div class="row margentop">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <mat-card>
            <span class="title-text">Comments</span>
            <div class="container-fluid p-t-15"></div>
            <div class="container-fluid p-t-15"></div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4 asdadsasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasDASDASD</div>
             <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
             <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
           </div>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: r]

Answer (score 0):

Se resume a usar bien la propiedad `word-wrap` de CSS, mira el siguiente ejemplo (dale click en ejecutar):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.a {
  word-wrap: normal;
}

div.b {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The word-wrap Property</h1>

<h2>word-wrap: normal (default):</h2>
<div class="a"> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>

<h2>word-wrap: break-word:</h2>
<div class="b"> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Por cierto, tu caso, nada tiene que ver con Angular, ni con Bootstrap, es solo CSS puro.

Referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp